# Symfony Bootstrap 4 Form Layout Inheritance

Tags: forms, symfony, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to override some fields of bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig, but i found some problems with radio_widget block. I need to change the div element to label, but when I ovverride the block, the radio element is duplicated on view. The div in question is that with class `custom-control`

```
{% block radio_widget %}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) %}
    {% if 'radio-custom' in parent_label_class %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' custom-control-input')|trim}) %}
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio{{ 'radio-inline' in parent_label_class ? ' custom-control-inline' }}">
            {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-check-input')|trim}) %}
        <div class="form-check{{ 'radio-inline' in parent_label_class ? ' form-check-inline' }}">
            {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Analizyng the dom with the console, I see that are created two element with `custom-control` class. Why?

[image]

Comment: imho SelectType is a monster when it comes to it's html code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I override the block **radio_widget** and changed the div element with label:

```
{% block radio_widget %}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) %}
    {% if 'radio-custom' in parent_label_class %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' custom-control-input')|trim}) %}
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio{{ 'radio-inline' in parent_label_class ? ' custom-control-inline' }}">
            {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
        </label>
    {% else %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-check-input')|trim}) %}
        <div class="form-check{{ 'radio-inline' in parent_label_class ? ' form-check-inline' }}">
            {{ form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Then I override also the block **checkbox_radio_label**. Inside it I substituted the base code:

```
// ...
{{ widget|raw }}
// ...
```

With:

```
{% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' custom-control-input')|trim}) %}
<input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

For reference about bootstrap 4 twig blocks see this link:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig